# Fitnesse: Could not find or load main class

Tags: fitnesse

When I run a test I get the below error:

```
Error: Could not find or load main class C:\GrowthEdition.QA\fitnesse\fitSharp\Runner.exe
```

The runner is in the specified location.
In the suitesetup I have defined the test runner:

```
variable defined: TEST_RUNNER=C:\GrowthEdition.QA\fitnesse\fitSharp\Runner.exe
```

What could be causing this issue, and how can I resolve it?

Many Thanks,
Rahul Dixit

Answer (score 0):

please ignore. 
I dont, know what I did differently, but it suddenly started working again.